# avl tree - ll rotate problam

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I've been trying to debug my code for over an hour and I can't understand what is the problem.
I have this class as Vertex:

```
class avl_node {
public:
    T data;
    int value;
    int high;
    avl_node *left, *right;
    avl_node *parent;
```

and I have this tree (before and after trying to insert 21 to the tree):
[image: I am losing info]

This is the ll rotate function:

```
Status ll_rotation(avl_node<T> *v) {
    avl_node<T>* tmp = v->left;
    v->left = tmp->right;
    if (tmp->right){
        tmp->right->parent = v;
    }
    tmp->right = v;
    tmp->parent = v->parent;
    v->parent = tmp;
    if (this->root == v) {
        this->root = tmp;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the `left` or `right` pointer of the parent of `v`. There may be some other issues, as well. Here is some code from my working implementation. The variable names are different, but you can compare it with yours and see what operations you're missing. The `update_height` function that is called at the end traverses up the tree updating the height of every node as it goes.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
void AVLTree<K,V>::right_rotate(AVLNode<K,V> *node)
{
    auto hold = node->left;
    if (node == root)
    {
        root = hold;
    }
    else if (node == node->parent->left)
    {
        node->parent->left = hold;
    }
    else
    {
        node->parent->right = hold;
    }

    hold->parent = node->parent;
    node->left = node->left->right;
    if (node->left)
    {
        node->left->parent = node;
    }
    hold->right = node;
    node->parent = hold;
    update_height(node);
}
```

Comment: Consider accepting this answer if it did indeed answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you traced your `ll_rotate` action on paper?  Whatever `v->left` points to at the start of the function is lost, since you never reassign `tmp` to the proper child node of `v`'s original parent.

Comment: yes i did, step by step.
Clion debuger says it's perfect at the end of the function, just when i get out i am loosing info